# Catch Exception on Build Method in AsynNotifier Riverpod

Tags: riverpod

```dart
@riverpod
class MyServiceController extends _$MyServiceController {
  static final Logger _logger = Logger('MyServiceController');
  @override
  FutureOr<bool?> build() async {
    _logger.info('MyServiceController.build');

    ref.onDispose(() {
      _logger.info('MyServiceController.onDispose');
    });
    try {
      final currentAccount = await ref.read(authRepoProvider).currentUser;
      final rep = await ref
          .read(servicesProvider)
          .hasService(userId: currentAccount.$id);
      return rep;
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I used try and catch here in the build method,so then it will not affect my screen. If ever there is an error occured we will return null. Also I override this Provider in a specific page, so then this specific page will only have this provider. Something like this.

```dart
ProviderScope(
override:[
  myServiceControllerProvider.overrideWith(MyServiceController.new)
]);
```

It is expected that whenever the user proceed to another page the build method of that provider will automatically triggered. That is why we have try and catch in build method it because to avoid 'hang' or lag something that will stuck on that page, whenever there is an error occurred (base in my experience in development phase not in release mode).But this is I want:

1. If the user proceed to another page, then the build method will trigger from that provider
2. I want to remove the try and catch here, I want to have this:

```dart
  @override
 FutureOr<bool?> build() async {
   _logger.info('MyServiceController.build');
   state = const AsyncLoading(); //added

   ref.onDispose(() {
     _logger.info('MyServiceController.onDispose');
   });
   try {
     final currentAccount = await ref.read(authRepoProvider).currentUser;
     final rep = await ref
         .read(servicesProvider)
         .hasService(userId: currentAccount.$id);
     state = AsyncValue.data(rep);//added
     return rep;
   } catch (e,stacktrace) {
     state = AsyncValue.error(e,stacktrace);//added
     return null;
   }
```

As you can see in build method we add state implementation here. So then in the screen will appear that there is an error then press the button if you want to retry. Overall, What I want is that is it okay to delete the try and catch? Because we know if we return a value here in a build method then the state of that provider has data, but what I want if there is an error then the state of that provider has error.

Comment: What does the "bool" represent?  Why are you using a try/catch instead of an AsyncNotifier's natural catch which would map it to an AsyncError?

Comment: Also what is "$id"?

Comment: it just representing if this currently user login  has service created , it will return if true otherwise it returns false. And obviously, id is the identification unique of the current user login